# ToastAndroid.CENTER / ToastAndroid.TOP does not change the position of my toast in android

Tags: android, react-native

I am using ToastAndroid for showing toast in my react native app. I am showing the toast on. button click as shown below.

```
const showToast = msg => {
    if(Platform.OS === 'android'){
      ToastAndroid.showWithGravityAndOffset(msg, ToastAndroid.LONG, ToastAndroid.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }else{
      Toast.showWithGravity(msg, Toast.SHORT, Toast.TOP);
    }
  };
```

The iOS toast changes it position but the android toast is still shown at the bottom of the screen. Not sure what is wrong. I am using **react-native 0.66.3**

Comment: Check the Android version you're testing on: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#text-toast-api-changes.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the quick help. setGravity() is no-op from targetSDK 30 or higher it seems. Is there a way where i can tweak it and still change its gravity? @MikeM.

Comment: Not that I've seen. I never went digging for a workaround, though, 'cause it didn't seem like a big issue to me. If you really want that kind of control over it, it's probably wiser to use your own `PopupWindow` or something similar, but that might not be so simple in your framework.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @MikeM.